# How can I test an IF statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

How can I test an IF statement in MySQL ?

I need to know, what happens when a query is into a `IF` statement and it returns nothing *(0 row selected)* ?

In other word, what a `SELECT` query returns when the no row is selected? Will it return `NULL`? If yes, so will this throw an error? `IF ( NULL ) THEN ...`? Or in this case just the statement of that `IF` won't execute?

---

In reality, I have a code like this:

```
IF ( SELECT banned FROM users WHERE id=new.user_id ) THEN 
// do stuff
```

**Note:** `banned` column contains either `0` or `1`.

All I want to know, is my code safe when that query doesn't return any row? I mean will it throw an error or nothing happens *(just that `IF` statement doesn't execute)* ?

---

Noted that I wanted to test it myselft, but I don't know how can I test a `IF` statement in MySQL. For example, I wanted to test it by this code:

```
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT banned FROM users WHERE id=new.user_id ) THEN 
       SELECT 'test';
    ENDIF;
END
```

But code above doesn't even run. That's why I've asked this question.

Comment: SQL doesn't have IF statements in it.  You can write stored procedures, but those are specific to MySQL and won't run in any other relational database.

Comment: @duffymo Ok thank you .. what you said explains why my code doesn't work. Just can you please tell me what happens when a sub-query returns nothing and it is into `IF` statement? Will it throw an error or just `ELSE` block executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IF` statement can be tested in the context of a MySQL stored program (a procedure, function or trigger.) MySQL doesn't support anonymous blocks.

To test an `IF` statement, you can create a procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo
BEGIN
  IF ( some_condition ) THEN
     SELECT 'evaluation of some_condition returned TRUE' AS msg;
  ELSE
     SELECT 'evaluation of some_condition did NOT return TRUE' AS msg;
  END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;

CALL foo;
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. but my main question is, what happens when a sub-query returns nothing and it is into `IF` statement? Will it throw an error or just `ELSE` block executes?

Comment: My misunderstanding. I thought you were asking how to test an IF statement.

Comment: Ok nevermind .. I myself will test it. Just onething else, a procedure is temporary or mandatory? I mean when I write `CREATE PROCEDURE foo`, a procedure will be created forever? And can I use `foo` every time I want?

Comment: `DROP PROCEDURE foo;`  Yes, procedure `foo` will be retained until it is dropped. If it's just for a temporary test, drop the procedure, but retain the script used to create it. You can use any valid identifier for the procedure. You might want to adopt a naming convention that allows you to easily identify "test" procedures that can be dropped.

Comment: @stack Stored procedures should be used very sparingly and for things that are unlikely to change frequently. Putting a lot of application logic directly in the database is nothing but trouble in the long haul, it's very difficult to version correctly and reproducing problems on different versions of the database can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know, what happens when a query is into a IF statement and it returns nothing (0 row selected) ?

What you're actually asking about here is a scalar subquery.

Scalar subqueries return exactly one column and exactly one or zero rows.  Returning `NULL` and matching zero rows are equivalent, and neither will throw an error.  In both cases, the subquery's return "value" is `NULL`.

You *will*, however, throw an error if you manage to write a scalar subquery that returns more than one row (such as when you forget `WHERE` in the subquery.  But zero rows is perfecty valid.

`IF` tests for truthiness, and anything that `IS TRUE` ... which technically means any expression that **both** `IS NOT FALSE` *and* `IS NOT NULL` -- satisfies the `IF`.  If the return value is `FALSE` (0) or `NULL` then the `ELSE` branch will be followed, if present.

I highlighted keyword phrases like `IS NOT FALSE`, above, to emphasize the point that these are logical operators in  SQL.

Try queries like `SELECT 0 IS FALSE` (returns 1, because it is) or `SELECT NULL IS NOT TRUE` (returns 1, because it isn't) or `SELECT NULL IS NOT FALSE` (also returns 1, because it isn't) `SELECT NULL IS FALSE` (returns 0, because it isn't) to see what I mean.